# Setting Variable Before Out-Null While Suppressing Output PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to suppress the output of a command while setting a variable. I need to do this because I have compiled the PowerShell Script using [PS2EXE-GUI](https://github.com/MScholtes/Win-PS2EXE). This program shows all command output on a seperate window, which is very annoying and is not necessary. I am trying to use `Get-ChildItem "$MYSQLFOLDERLOCATION" | Out-String | Write-Host`, but this only works when there is nothing in the directory, anything else, and it shows the directory contents on the screen. I have also been trying to use `Get-ChildItem "$MYSQLFOLDERLOCATION" | $ISMYSQLFOLDERPRESENT = $? | Out-Null`, but this is syntactically incorrect. Is there something similar to this that I can use? I basically want to do an *ls*-equivalent command in PowerShell, then store whether it succeeded or not, while not showing anything on screen (I can't use *Write-Output*, *Write-Host*, etc.)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `$IsMySqlFolderPresent = Test-Path $MYSQLFOLDERLOCATION -PathType Container`?

Comment: Precisely! I'm new to PowerShell and never knew this existed :) If you would like to turn that into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Agreed, Get-Childitem is the wrong command here. And using Write-Host exacerbates the problem as it will always output to the console whatever else you do. Test-Path is the way.

Comment: I am coming from a non-Windows environment (Linux-type) and I always used *ls*, set variable, *clear* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign *the entire expression* to a variable - otherwise any resulting output will "bubble up" to the caller and you'll see it on the screen:

```
$variable = Get-ChildItem .\path
```

For checking whether a folder *exists* in the file system or not, I'd suggest using `Test-Path` instead of `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$IsMySqlFolderPresent = Test-Path $MYSQLFOLDERLOCATION -PathType Container
```

`$IsMySqlFolderPresent` will now hold a boolean value (`$true` or `$false`) depending on whether a directory exists at the path specified by `$MYSQLFOLDERLOCATION`